# How to fix a changing xPath in search box (doesn't contain text)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Basically I want to input invoices in Xero software for my job. The process is very simple, I have some values that I need to input in some slots. I have a big problem however. The `xpath` is dynamic (changes every time you refresh). 
Basically it changes from something like this:

`//*[@id="PaidToName_12ddc347c7bc4f5aa84c452f55660690_value"]`

To something like this:

`//*[@id="PaidToName_4fea44e4f8a844b4b630b4bf149490d8_value"]`

So the numbers keep on changing. 
I have tried a `starts-with` function however I am pretty sure that there are two XPATHs that starts with `PaidToName` or end with `value`, therefore this doesn't seem like a solution as I get this error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

The other thing to note is that I see many elements that have the "input type hidden" in the HTML code which I am pretty sure play a role with that. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to help.

This is the code I have tried that doesn't work.

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'PaidToName')]")
button.send_keys('lol')
```

This is the HTML code I am trying to retrieve

```
<input type="text" size="24" autocomplete="off" id="PaidToName_4fea44e4f8a844b4b630b4bf149490d8_value" name="PaidToName_4fea44e4f8a844b4b630b4bf149490d8_value" class="x-form-text x-form-field autocompleter x-form-focus" tabindex="10" style="width: 129px;">
```

Comment: Are you sure that screen-scraping is the right approach to this? Doesn't Xero have a suitable API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath` with `id` and `class` combination, try this :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'PaidToName') and contains(@class,'x-form-text')]")
button.send_keys('lol')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below given locator.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'PaidToName') AND contains(@class,'x-form-text')]")
```